# Extending HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototyping

using jQuery it is possible to do something like this: `$("div")[5].animate()`

This seems to me like the developers in a way extended the `HTMLElement` using `prototype`.

My question is now: How did they do this? Since `HTMLElement.prototype` is not working in IE for example I wonder if there is a cross browser method to prototype HTML elements.

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to do something like $("div").eq(5).animate()?

Comment: according to http://api.jquery.com/animate/
the syntax is like $('#book').animate(...)
where $('#book') is just a selector and that means that every html element seems to "inherit" that method

Comment: I don't watn do do something specifically it's just a question of how to cross-browser extending/prototypeing html elements

Comment: note that `$('#book') !== document.getElementById('book')` the first one is a jQuery object which refers to a dom element and can be extended, while the second one is actually a dom element.

Comment: ahhhh
that's the point..
okay, i got it, thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extend those things in IE; IE just does not implement the DOM interface that way.  That's why Prototype forces you to "wrap" elements that you want to manipulate with those additional methods.

Comment: I am not talking about the framework Prototype.
Obviously, it is possible as it is used in jQuery.

Comment: No, jQuery does not extend the DOM element interface directly (the way Prototype *does* extend it).  The Prototype library, in browsers that support it, extends the DOM element prototypes with additional methods.  However, it can't do that in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

the jQuery factory function (`jQuery()` or `$()`) ***does not return a DOM node***.

The jQuery factory function returns a new `jQuery.init` instance which acts very similar to an array. Instead of extending any DOM node's prototype, more functions are simply added to `jQuery.fn`

If a function is chained on a jQuery selector, it typically applies to *all* the elements contained within the jQuery.init instance.

I highly recommend reading through the [commented jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) so that you can see exactly what's going on behind-the-scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `$('#book') !== document.getElementById('book')`.
The first one is a jQuery object which refers to a dom element and can be extended, while the second one is actually a dom element.